# "curl: (7) Failed to connect to myapp-backend-api port 81: Connection refused" + different docker compose files + cant expose ports internally?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two docker-compose files where each contains different services. By creating an external network and defining such network to each compose files, I was able to have a shared network between each containers and all containers are accessible via their hostnames. I can ping  each containers that were created from these separate compose files via their hostnames. The problem Im having is that I could not curl a certain service via their exposed port. Actually, my goal is to access the rest api myapp-backend-api:81 from my myapp_frontend_php. May I know what is lacking from my setup?

Here are the results from ping and curl:

```
root@myapp-encryption-flask:/var/www# ping -c 3 myapp-backend-api
PING myapp-backend-api (172.18.0.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from abkd-proxy-1.myapp-shared-network (172.18.0.7): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms   
64 bytes from abkd-proxy-1.myapp-shared-network (172.18.0.7): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.206 ms
64 bytes from abkd-proxy-1.myapp-shared-network (172.18.0.7): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms

--- myapp-backend-api ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2076ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.052/0.106/0.206/0.070 ms
root@myapp-encryption-flask:/var/www# curl myapp-backend-api:81
curl: (7) Failed to connect to myapp-backend-api port 81: Connection refused
root@myapp-encryption-flask:/var/www#
```

Here is compose file 1:

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: myapp-shared-network

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3301:3306"
    hostname: myapp-db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - production_db_volume:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - .env.dev

  # or
  #  db:
  #    image: postgres:12.5
  #    ports:
  #      - "5432:5432"
  #    restart: always
  #    volumes:
  #      - production_db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  #    env_file:
  #      - .env.dev


  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    volumes:
      - production_static_data:/vol/web
    hostname: myapp-backend
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    hostname: myapp-backend-api
    volumes:
      - production_static_data:/vol/static
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    depends_on:
      - app


volumes:
  production_static_data:
  production_db_volume:
```

And, here is compose file 2

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: myapp-shared-network

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./myapp_frontend_php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: myapp-app
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19-alpine
    hostname: myapp-nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d

  myapp-processor:
    build:
      context: ./myapp_encryption_flask
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: myapp-processor
    container_name: myapp-processor
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
```

Comment: Have you checked your **Firewall**? It might be the reason for blocking that connection.

Comment: i have not checked it but I can access all of my apps in my browser via localhost and localhost:81